# Allow group as public on MSSQL server and set db privileges for user's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I moved a couple of MSSQL databases to a different cluster and want to change the way privileges are distributed. I created a group in AD and created a public login for that group. Every user who needs to access the cluster should be in that group.

The privileges on the db should then be set for every user.

So the login would be allowed for the group and the db privileges for each user.
[image: a screenshot of the 'Database User - New' window in MSSQL]
[image: screenshot of error message]

Is there a way to do this or is this not possible?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: I strongly recommend you *don't* use the GUI to do these tasks, write the T-SQL out. If you *must* (you don't) use the GUI then script the T-SQL it's going to run out, validate and check it, alter and needed, and run that. For the above, can you share the T-SQL that is being run please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. As I mentioned don't use the GUI for this, instead use T-SQL.

To achieve this, is quite simple, `CREATE` a `LOGIN` for the AD Group and then, in the database, `CREATE` a `USER` for the Windows user.

```sql
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN [YourDomain\YourADGroup] FROM WINDOWS;
GO

USE YourDatabase;
GO

CREATE USER [YourDomain\YourADUser];
GO
```

When the Windows User attempts to authenticate to the instance they will be granted permission to connect due to their AD Group. Then when they want to connect to the specific databases, they're be granted permission by the AD User.

If you need to give the `LOGIN` permissions then `GRANT`/`DENY` them to the `LOGIN` `[YourDomain\YourADGroup]` or give it a server role (`ALTER SERVER ROLE ... ADD MEMBER ...`). If you need to give specific permissions in the database then do so to the `USER`s, or assign the appropriate `ROLE`s to it.

Comment: & as the error message says you'll also have to avoid using invalid characters in your user/login names

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought in the first place. There are no invilaid characters except the backslash. When I tried to create the user with domain\username as login name, it accepts the input. This looks like a GUI problem regarding to the answer from Thom A.